# A short way to map an object - previous key is a value and previous value is a value - in the new object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I am trying to turn this object:

```
{
    "loose-envify": "^1.1.0",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2"
}
```

to:

```
{
    {
        name: "loose-envify", 
        version: "^1.1.0" 
    }, 
    {
        name: "object-assign", 
        version: "^4.1.1"
    }, 
    {
        same here...
    }
}
```

I am trying to use map to do this in one line, but not sure how.
is it even possible? if not, what is?

Comment: I certainly is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What sort of object is the output? Did you mean an array instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you were looking for?

*(Your question shows an invalid object with missing keys so I assumed you meant an array...)*

```js
const oldObj = {
    "loose-envify": "^1.1.0",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
};

const newObj = Object.entries(oldObj).map(([name,version]) => ({
  name,
  version,
}));

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: You can also `map` over `Object.keys` but `entries` seemed more appropriate here.